# NextJS Api node modules path on Vercel deployment

Tags: api, next.js, vercel, prettier

I am generating a file inside nextJs api function and I format it there with prettier.
Everything works fine when hosted locally but on Vercel the plugin I load cannot be found.

I use:

```
  const formattedContract = prettier.format(newContract, {
    parser: "solidity-parse",
    pluginSearchDirs: ["node_modules"],
    plugins: ["prettier-plugin-solidity"],
  });

  fs.writeFileSync(`/tmp/${contractId}.sol`, formattedContract);
```

Error I am getting (from Vercel logs):

```
[POST] /api/generateContract
14:03:48:05
2023-01-06T13:03:53.774Z    4a4f5046-e8e7-4f0c-8f28-514637b2accb    ERROR   Error: Cannot find module 'prettier-plugin-solidity'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/prettier/index.js
- /var/task/.next/server/pages/api/generateContract.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
- /var/task/___next_launcher.cjs
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at mod._resolveFilename (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
    at resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at /var/task/node_modules/prettier/index.js:37772:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.load (/var/task/node_modules/prettier/index.js:37767:65)
    at Object.load [as loadPlugins] (/var/task/node_modules/prettier/index.js:15932:23)
    at /var/task/node_modules/prettier/index.js:37834:24
    at Object.format (/var/task/node_modules/prettier/index.js:37850:12)
    at handler (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/generateContract.js:72:79) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/task/node_modules/prettier/index.js',
    '/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/generateContract.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js',
    '/var/task/___next_launcher.cjs'
  ]
}
```

What is the correct path to node modules on Vercel?

I have tried putting it on the default path `/` and `node_modules`.

EDIT: For some reason the plugin was not imported into the server node-modules. I have added
`import 'prettier-plugin-solidity';` on top of the file for it to be included.